C# Source Generator Native Marshaling - Use Type Defined in Another Assembly?
We're currently modernizing our native interop implementations for marshaling data between C# and mainly C++ using source generators together with MarshalUsing attributes and CustomMarshallers, etc.
A few of the custom marshaling types we use are currently defined in their own C# project, and this seems to make problems with the new code; it works if the type is defined in the same project that does the calls into the native code, but when they are defined in the project that used to be shared between all those that had to do this kind of marshaling, we get a
First Chance Exception System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Cannot marshal 'return value': Non-blittable generic types cannot be marshaled.
from within g____PInvoke, and before the custom marshallers even come into action.
This happens even with very simple (record or not) struct types with just one member, etc. There's no generics involved, other than of course in the PInvoke stuff itself that's being generated.
We tested the scenario a little, and it seems to come down to

literally just moving the type this happens with over from the other project—it works
moving it back to the other project—the error is thrown

Does anyone know if there's an easy workaround for this, or maybe even a fix (maybe a project setting that's now necessary or so)?

If you're going to refactor... and you're doing code generation : maybe don't use pInvoke, but write/generate an interop layer in managed C++/cli. (Gives you a lot more control on when to copy, modify and pin data)
